# why am not able to display data if inserting a new node in a empty circular lined list?

Tags: python, data-structures

Below is the code snippet to add node in two scenario

- if the circular linked list is empty
- Add node at the end of the circular linked list

```py
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.start = None
    
    class cLL:
        def __init__(self):
            self.start = Node(None)
            self.last = Node(None)
            self.start.nxt = self.last
            self.last.nxt = self.start
            
        def addEmpty(self, val):
            nu = Node(val)
            if self.start.data == None:
                self.start = nu
                self.last = nu
                nu.nxt = self.start
            return nu
                
        def addEnd(self, val):
            nu = Node(val)
            if self.start == None:
                print("no nodes at the beginning")
            else:
                self.last.nxt = nu
                self.last = nu
                nu.nxt = self.start
                
        def display(self):
            tmp = self.start
            while tmp.nxt != self.last.nxt:
                tmp = tmp.nxt
                print(tmp.data)
                
    rew = cLL()
    rew.addEmpty(23)
    rew.addEnd(30)
    rew.addEnd(90)
    rew.addEnd(900)
    rew.display()
```

But the function "addEmpty()" is not working. The display function is not able to show it. Please suggest

Comment: because when the only node you've added is the one from `addEmpty` then this check is false `while tmp.nxt != self.last.nxt`

Comment: so,  what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- A circular list should not be initiated with two nodes (having `None` as data), but with **no** nodes.
- When adding a node to an empty list, you should not assign that node reference to both `start` and `last`, as that gives you a duplicate node for no good reason. If then later you mutate `start`, you'll be mutating the node that also `last` references, and vice versa. This will almost always have undesired effects.
- A `Node` instance should not get a `start` attribute in its constructor, but should instead get an initialised `nxt` attribute.
- The `display` method is printing not printing the data of the `start` node, but it is printing the data of the `last` node. This is confusing. That function should display all node's data.

For a circular list you actually don't need both a `start` and `last` reference. Either the list is empty, or else the `start` node will **always** be the one referenced by `last.nxt` (if there are no errors). So that means you can do with only the `last` attribute and drop the `start` attribute. This will also save you some code.

It is not clear why you would have a different method for adding a node to an empty list, than for adding a node to a non-empty list. Just use one method and make the distinction with an `if`, which anyway you already have for checking the list is empty or not.

Here is a corrected version:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        # A node has a nxt attribute, not start.
        # As a circular list NEVER has None-references, make this a self refence
        self.nxt = self

class cLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = None  # Don't create a node here! No need for `start`
        
    def addEnd(self, val):  # One method, not two
        nu = Node(val)
        if self.last is None:
            self.last = nu
        else:
            nu.nxt = self.last.nxt
            self.last.nxt = nu
            self.last = nu
            
    def display(self):
        if not self.last:
            return  # nothing to print
        tmp = self.last.nxt
        print(tmp.data)
        while tmp != self.last:
            tmp = tmp.nxt
            print(tmp.data)
        
rew = cLL()
rew.addEnd(23)
rew.addEnd(30)
rew.addEnd(90)
rew.addEnd(900)
rew.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your display function is incorrect, you are never printing the start value as you go to the next one before printing. An example answer would be to add a print statement before the while loop starts. Hope this helps:

```
def display(self):
    tmp = self.start
    print(tmp.data)
    while tmp.nxt != self.last.nxt:
        tmp = tmp.nxt
        print(tmp.data)
```